# django water mark procedure in uploaded images

Tags: python, django, watermark

I am using django watermark for watermarking my website images.I have completed all the settings according to this https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-watermark/.

Here is my settings.py file(only the change  have made associated with watermark is showing here)

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'django.contrib.admin',

    'photo',
    'userena',
    'guardian',
    'easy_thumbnails',
    'accounts',

    'paypal.standard.ipn',
    'myprofile',
    'watermarker',
```

)

```
WATERMARKING_QUALITY = 85
WATERMARK_OBSCURE_ORIGINAL = False
```

now according to the above link i have uploaded an transparent PNG image namely Medical Art in the watermark table of my database,now i have applied the watermark in the following template like this...

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}
{% load watermark %}
{% block title %}ShutterStock{%endblock%}


{% block content %}



 <ul> 

{% for photo in photo_list%}
  <li><a href = "{% url 'download_image' photo.id %}"><img src={{photo.photo.url|watermark: 'Medical Art,opacity=40,tile=1'}} alt = 'sample photo' width = '200' height = '200'/></li></a>
{% endfor %}
</ul>





{% endblock %}
```

in mention,the images i am showing is the uploaded image.But  i am getting the following error after running the website,that is

IOError at /showphoto/

decoder zip not available

Comment: Trying removing the space and using `"` quotes...

Answer (score 0):

Remove space between `filter` and argument:

```
{{photo.photo.url|watermark: 'Medical Art,opacity=40,tile=1'}}
                            ^
```

---

Example:

- without space:

  ```
  >>> from django.template import Template, Context
  >>> Template('''{{nothing|default:'HELLO'}}''').render(Context({}))
  u'HELLO'
  ```
- with space:

  ```
  >>> Template('''{{nothing|default: 'HELLO'}}''').render(Context({}))
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/home/falsetru/.virtualenvs/django16/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 125, in __init__
      self.nodelist = compile_string(template_string, origin)
    File "/home/falsetru/.virtualenvs/django16/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 153, in compile_string
      return parser.parse()
    File "/home/falsetru/.virtualenvs/django16/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 254, in parse
      filter_expression = self.compile_filter(token.contents)
    File "/home/falsetru/.virtualenvs/django16/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 360, in compile_filter
      return FilterExpression(token, self)
    File "/home/falsetru/.virtualenvs/django16/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 572, in __init__
      self.args_check(filter_name, filter_func, args)
    File "/home/falsetru/.virtualenvs/django16/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 641, in args_check
      (name, len(nondefs), plen))
  TemplateSyntaxError: default requires 1 arguments, 0 provided
  ```

Comment: now showing this error IOError at /showphoto/

decoder zip not available

Comment: @zogo, It seems like the error is raised by PIL. Check if the url is referencing a valid image url.

Comment: @zogo, See [google search result for `IOError: decoder zip not available`](http://www.google.com/search?q="IOError%3A+decoder+zip+not+available")